# Oracle SQL Joining 2 Queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to form a query using 2 other queries, but I don't know how I would do it exactly.  I am using Oracle SQL.  Here is the basic logic:

if `(select supervisor_id from PS_EMPLOYEES where EMPLID = %This.sEMPLID)` 
is in

```
(select EMPLID from sysadm.PS_Z_RPT_TO_REL where Z_DIRECT_RPT = 'D' where manager_id =  %EmployeeID)
```

return True else return False.

Basically the first query will have an ID and will search through a list formed from the second query.  If the ID from the first query is in the list from the second query then return 'True' else return 'False'  Any thoughts?

Comment: SQL queries return rows and columns, not scalar expressions.  Can you be clearer about what you are trying to do?  Sample data and desired results are a big help.

Comment: The first query provides an ID.  The second query provides a list of IDs.  If the ID in the first query is in the list from the second query I want to provide a value of "True".  If the ID from the first query is not in the second query I want to provide a value of "False"

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following perhaps (untested):

```
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT supervisor_id 
  FROM PS_EMPLOYEES 
  WHERE EMPLID = %This.sEMPLID
  AND supervisor_id IN (
    SELECT EMPLID 
    FROM sysadm.PS_Z_RPT_TO_REL 
    WHERE Z_DIRECT_RPT = 'D' 
    AND manager_id LIKE  %EmployeeID
  )
)
```

Comment: that's close...I think it needs to be something more like this:SELECT * from  (
  SELECT supervisor_id 
  FROM PS_EMPLOYEES 
  WHERE EMPLID = %This.sEMPLID
  AND supervisor_id IN (
    SELECT EMPLID 
    FROM sysadm.PS_Z_RPT_TO_REL 
    WHERE Z_DIRECT_RPT = 'D' 
    AND manager_id LIKE  %EmployeeID
  )
)

Comment: I think you may have responded to the original post after I already corrected it? (I don't see any differences between your comment and what I've got?)